# Fetching boolean value from request

Tags: python, falconframework

I am fetching a boolean value from the request in falcon API.

Sample url :

`localhost:8080/api/some-end-point/101?something=true`

I want

```
----------------------------------
| something     | Something_flag |
----------------------------------
| true          | True           |
----------------------------------
| false         | False          |
----------------------------------
| not provided  | True           |
----------------------------------
```

Code:

```
something_flag = req.get_param_as_bool('something') \
        if req.get_param_as_bool('something') else True
```

Is there any *better* pythonic way to do this?

Comment: I don't get your question. Presumably `req.get_param_as_bool('something')` returns a bool, as the name implies. So why not just `something = req.get_param_as_bool('something')`?

Comment: @DanielRoseman what if req.get_param_as_bool('something') is None

Comment: Well if it can return None then it is misnamed. But then `bool(req.get_param_as_bool('something'))` would work.

Comment: @DanielRoseman bool(None) will return false

Comment: @DanielRoseman I edited my question for further clarification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not a simple:

```
something_flag = req.get_param_as_bool('something') != False

True != False  # >>> True
False != False  # >>> False
None != False  # >>> True
```

Comment: `something_flag = req.get_param_as_bool('something') is not False` looks better than  the code in the question

Comment: Is the `something` returned `'false'` (string) or `False` (boolean)?

Comment: `something` is string and `get_param_as_bool` will return boolean  - True/False/None

Comment: Ok, I fixed it then. In that particular case, I find the 'different of' operator more intuitive than a `is not` statement, since we are checking the value, not the identity of the objects. But both solutions are ok...

Answer (score 1):

```
something_flag = req.get_param_as_bool('something') \
        if req.get_param('something') is not None else True
```

Or you could use the argument [default](https://falcon.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/request_and_response.html#falcon.Request.get_param_as_bool)

```
something_flag = req.get_param_as_bool('something', default=True)
```

For version 1.2, there is no `default`, you could use `required`.

```
try:
    something_flag = req.get_param_as_bool('something', required=True)
except HTTPBadRequest:
    something_flag = True
```

Comment: `if req.get_param('something')` looks better and readable than `if req.get_param('something') is not None`. No?

Comment: @devツ Maybe, if you would also want to consider when the param was given with empty string. Check out the [doc](https://falcon.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/request_and_response.html#falcon.Request.get_param).

Comment: @devツ I edited the response, better use `default` :)

Comment: Thanks. Looks like `default` is not there in Falcon 1.2.

Comment: The 1st answer in your answer is doing the same as the code mentioned in the question.

Comment: The code in the question gives always `True`. Mine gives `True` if the param was not given; the actual value otherwise.